# Mosaic plot from count data with JMP

Tags: graph, graphics, statistics, contingency, sas-jmp

I am trying to make a mosaic plot with JMP where the data are already in form of frequencies. I would know how to make a mosaic plot where the frequencies are given by the number of occurences in my data but not when the frequency is directly indicated.

For example consider the following data. There are three variables Smoke (Y/N), Cancer(Y/N) and NbInds (number of individuals falling into this bucket). Here are some examples of values, where smoke,NoCancer,n would mean that we observed $n$ individuals smoking but not having cancer. Here are my made-up data:

```
smoke,cancer,10
smoke,nocancer,1000
nosmoke,cancer,8
nosmoke,nocancer,3000
```

For example that means that there are 8 people who don't smoke and had a cancer.

**How should I enter these data in JMP (in three columns?) and how do I make a mosaic plot with them then?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Frequency put column 3 in as a weight.